# Какие шаблоны лучше использовать в многоцелевой CMS?

Tags: php, cms, html

Доброго всем дня!

Интересует мнение большинства, какие шаблоны лучше использовать в многоцелевой `CMS`? Что лучше: `php+html, smarty, twig`...?

Хотелось бы получить максимум отзывов (без "религиозных" споров) просто по делу, нравится ... потому что ...

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я тоже постоянно в своих работах стараюсь не пользоваться Фрейворками и т.п-ми... считаю, что тормозят... хотя говорят, очень удобно...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Многое зависит от того, какие требований к шаблонизатору. Так например, одни шаблонизаторы могут быть более гибкими, вторые более быстрыми, третьи лучше отделяют логику от представления.

Из тех шаблонизаторов, с которыми мне приходилось работать самому, я бы мог выделить следующие:

---

Шаблоны на "чистом" php, будем называть их **php mess**.

- **Возможности**. Тут все понятно. Все есть в вашем проекте, доступно и здесь "из коробки".
- **Скорость**. Так же очевидно, что скорость будет ограничиваться разве что кривизной шаблонов.
- **Расширяемость**. См. возможности.
- **Юзабилити**. А вот это пункт сводит на нет все преимущества предыдущих пунктов. Нет никакой разделяемости логики от представлений. Конструкции типа `<div><?php foreach ($var['foo'].bar(array(1, 2, 3)) as $key => $val) : ?php><?= $val ?><?php endforeach; ?></div>` как правило неизбежны и быстро превращают шаблон в жутчайшее месиво говнокода.

  Отсутствие каких-либо песочниц или ограничений на выполняемый код делают его настоящим генератором багов.

Крайне не рекомендовал бы использовать этот подход ни в каких проектах сложнее `Hello, World`.

---

**[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/index.tpl)** - старейший и хорошо всем известный шаблонизатор.

- **Возможности**. Имеются функции, модификаторы, ветвления, инклюды. Компилирует шаблоны в php mess. В общем, стандартный набор шаблонизатора. Ничего особо примечательного нету. Песочницы нету.
- **Скорость**. Написан на PHP, шаблоны компилирует в php mess. Но из-за большего overhead на обслуживание и выполнение шаблонов, достаточно медлителен. Хотя, начиная с версии 3 стал пошустрее, но все равно достаточно далек от идеала.
- **Расширяемость**. Можно создавать свои функции и модификаторы, которые будут выполняться в runtime. Собственно, все.
- **Юзабилити**. Хорошая документация. Синтаксис, на мой взгляд, хоть и не очень лаконичен, но понятен любому грамотному верстальщику. Однако, наличие тега ['{php}'](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl) и бесконтрольное добавление функций может легко превратить шаблон в месиво, похлеще чем встречается в php mess. Интегрируется со многими IDE.

Рекомендовал бы его только в случае, когда есть верстальщики уже работавшие с ним и не желающие что-либо переучивать.

---

**[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)** - новомодный шаблонизатор. Во многом схож с питоновским шаблонизатором [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).

- **Возможности**.  В чем-то схожи со Smarty. Те же модификаторы, циклы, ветвления, инкюды (но, к счастью, нету тега `{php}` или аналогов). Помимо этого предоставляет возможности блочной шаблонизации, [наследование шаблонов](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html), [макросы](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) и прочие мелкие полезности.

  Так же есть возможность [настраивать лексемы языковых конструкций](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax), что может упростить миграцию шаблонов других шаблонизаторов.

  Имеется песочница для безопасного выполнения шаблонов в изолированном окружении.
- **Скорость**. Сам Twig написан на чистом php. Компилирует шаблоны в php классы с последующим многократном использованием оных. Из коробки, в некоторых местах, проигрывает по скорости даже Smarty 3. Однако с использованием, [идущего в комплекте расширения на `C`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installing-the-c-extension) (которое содержит одну единственную функцию :)) можно получить вполне приемлемую производительность.
- **Расширяемость**. Тут Twig абсолютный лидер. Он позволяет [все](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html): от расширения языковых конструкций до создания своего компилятора шаблонов.

  Одной из примечательных особенностей можно отметить то, что можно писать расширения, которые будут работать на уровне компиляции. К примеру, не сложно написать расширение, удаляющее лишние пробелы из литералов один раз при компиляции, а не в runtime из всех переменных подряд. Или же можно написать расширение которое будет компилировать тот-же самый шаблон в чистый javascript.
- **Юзабилити**. Удобный лаконичный синтаксис. Некоторые конструкции, явно, позаимствованы из питона. Так же как и Smarty интегрируется со многими IDE.

Рекомендовал бы для всех проектов не слишком критичных к производительности или требующих очень тесную интеграцию шаблонизатора с основным проектом.

---

**[Blitz](http://alexeyrybak.com/blitz/blitz_en.html)** - безумно быстрый шаблонизатор от русского разработчика. Написан на `C`.

- **Возможности**. Блоки, переменные, примитивная конструкция IF и пользовательские функции. Все.
- **Скорость**. Это наверное единственный из всех используемых мной шаблонизаторов, который в некоторых случаях (как правило для сложных шаблонов с большим количеством блоков) по скорости превосходит даже php mess! Более быстрого шаблонизатора я еще не встречал.
- **Расширяемость**. Единственная возможность расширения - это пользовательские функции. Однако в качестве параметров функций могут выступать только переменные текущего контекста или скалярные литералы, что делает их несколько ограниченными в возможностях.
- **Юзабилити**. Синтаксис в виде HTML комментариев, плюс отсутствие всевозможных циклов, сложных ветвлений и т.п делает, на мой взгляд, шаблоны очень удобными для верстки. Ничего лишнего, в браузере сразу видно как будут выглядеть все блоки шаблона. Верстальщику не нужно учить никаких сложных конструкций.

  Для разработчика же все в точности до наоборот. В связи со спецификой шаблонизатора и ограниченной функциональности нужно подготавливать данные с заранее определенной структурой (см. раздел [15. Nested iterations](http://alexeyrybak.com/blitz/quick_geek.html)) или же вводить дополнительную прослойку, отвечающую за логику отображения.

Рекомендовал бы для любых highload проектов.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Исчерпывающий ответ!

Comment: ИМХО синтаксис последнего варианта - редкое УГ.

А вот пример использования т.н. 'php_mess' - не показателен( я бы сказал высосан из пальца ), к тому-же - нет, не неизбежно шаблон превращается в  месиво говнокода, практически все зависит от программиста, если голова темная и руки растут из Ж, то ни один шаблонизатор не спасет.

Если вас не затруднит - приведите пожалуйста пример, где нормально написанные 'php_mess' шаблон уступает по производительности Blitz. Не первый раз об этом читаю, но так и не нашел ни единого примера, только ничем не подкрепленные слова :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а мне Blitz понравился ^^  
но вряд ли он обгонит нативный PHP, даже на авторском сайте нет такой инфы вроде.

Comment: @Construct - рад за вас. Вот я тоже так считаю, в противовес, пока, ничего кроме отдельных, единичных, ничем не подкрепленных утверждений так и не нашел.

Comment: @Construct, в синтетических тестах не обгонит, конечно. Речь шла про "боевые" шаблоны, среди которых некоторые, после перехода на blitz, стали показывать результаты лучше.

@AlexWindHope, нет, я там уже давно не работаю.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы использовал нативный шаблон `html + php`.
Это достаточно быстрее чем Смарти, но будет проблематично верстальщику.
Для этого код просто выделять в блоки с комментариями.

Comment: Аналогично  html + css :)


Answer (score 1):

За всю свою жизнь не встретил ни одного верстальщика, которому было бы проблематично понять нечто вроде <?=$title?>.

Ответ на вопрос. Если CMS и правда многоцелевая, то xml. с помощью xslt можно сотворить очень многое.

Comment: "можно сотворить очень многое" - вы правы, но простите - зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Мне лично нравится мой самописный шаблонизатор (могу залить куда-нибудь; документации нет). Весит мало, умеет только то, что нужно: делать include в шаблон, дублировать блоки и вставлять значения в метки. Сами шаблоны напоминают html и не содержат в себе логики. То есть, прогер указывает верстаку, что будет выводиться на странице, а верстак уже решает, где это будет и как.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте любой шаблонизатор, если вы планируете пользоваться своей CMS больше одного раза :) Лучше всего использовать смарти, по которому много документации и с которым знакомы большинство верстальщиков и программистов. Лучше подключить его сразу, чем потом тратить кучу времени на переделку CMS под корректную работу с шаблонизаторами.

Насчет мнения, что смарти много весит и медленно работает - с чего вы взяли? Тем более дешевле прикупить хостинг по-мощнее, чем платить программисту, чтобы он навел порядок в шаблонах ;)

Comment: Я согласен с @FladeX, ибо смарти - простой шаблонизатор и умеет многое, да и инфы по нему море, особенно официальной :)